# how can i do this better?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have this code setup so that it changes force for a ship depending on its size.

```
function activateFly(ship, event)
    if(size == 0) then
        ship:applyForce(0, -2.5, ship.x, ship.y)
        print("FLY SIZE 0")     
    elseif(size == 1) then
        ship:applyForce(0, -2.3,ship.x, ship.y)
        print("FLY SIZE 1")
    elseif(size == 2) then
        ship:applyForce(0, -2.0, ship.x, ship.y)
        print("FLY SIZE 2")
    elseif(size == 3) then
        ship:applyForce(0, -0.8, ship.x, ship.y)
        print("FLY SIZE 3")
    end
end
```

This means I need to write endless if-else statements for all the different sizes. What I'm asking is if there is a code where i can take the size variable stored, multiply it by some number and set the force correctly? that way I don't need to write all those statements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, and would get better response on [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
local forceMap = {
    [0] = -2.5,
    [1] = -2.3,
    [2] = -2.0,
    [3] = -0.8,
}

function activateFly(ship, event)
    ship:applyForce(0, forceMap[size], ship.x, ship.y)
    print("FLY SIZE "..size)
end
```

If you happen to have a way to calculate the force from the size you could avoid using the mapping table and use the math instead.

Comment: You may want to move the definition of `forceMap` outside the function, to avoid creating the table on every call.

Comment: Good point, edited. I do that in my code normally.

Comment: Yeah something like that, but how do I get this to work? Do i add the ForceMap values into a gameloop? also how do i get it to work with the size variable i currently have?

Comment: That table is a direct translation of your snippet of code. If those are your actual values then (barring typos, etc.) my bit of code should function identically to your bit of code. If your table is static and be pre-computed (which I assume it can if you could hard-code the if statement version then you can just put this bit of code into your game in place of your original code and it should Just Work.